# What is the correct C# lambda syntax here?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to use lambda syntax to be able to swap out search rule engines at runtime.

In the below example, **what syntax do I need** to be able to pass the name of the method to my GetSearchResults method so that the GetSearchResults method can use the appropriate logic to decide which results to return?

```
string searchRulesMethodName = "SearchRules1(entry)";
var results = GetSearchResults(p => searchRulesMethodName);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestLambda2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string searchRulesMethodName = "SearchRules1(entry)";
            var results = GetSearchResults(p => searchRulesMethodName);
            foreach (string entry in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //only returns some entries
        public static bool SearchRules1(string entry)
        {
            if (entry == "one" || entry == "two") return true;
            return false;
        }

        //returns all entries
        public static bool SearchRules2(string entry)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static List<string> GetSearchResults(Predicate<string> p)
        {
            string[] allEntries = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" };
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            foreach (string entry in allEntries)
            {
                if (p.Invoke(entry))
                {
                    results.Add(entry);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

    }
}
```

### ANSWER:

Thanks Marc, that was exactly what I wanted to do. Using reflection also solved the "how do I tell it the property signature" problem as well:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string searchRulesMethodName = "SearchRules2";
    Predicate<string> predicate = (Predicate<string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Predicate<string>),
        typeof(Program).GetMethod(searchRulesMethodName));
    var results = GetSearchResults(predicate);

    foreach (string entry in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a string, you'd have to use reflection to get the delegate;

```
string searchRulesMethodName = "SearchRules1";
Predicate<string> predicate = (Predicate<string>)
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Predicate<string>),
        typeof(Program).GetMethod(searchRulesMethodName));
var results = GetSearchResults(predicate);
```

Of course, a `switch` would be a lot faster and safer if you know all the options at compile-time!

```
Predicate<string> predicate;
switch (searchRulesMethodName) {
    case "SearchRules1": predicate = SearchRules1; break;
    case "SearchRules2": predicate = SearchRules2; break;
    default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown filter: "
        + searchRulesMethodName);
}
var results = GetSearchResults(predicate);
```